# Why are links in HTML files with URI scheme tel: and sms: in href not working on Android?

Tags: android, html, sms, url-scheme, tel

On android (at least on some of my devices) links with `hrefs` pointing to `tel:` and `sms:` URIs are not working. Instead of opening the SMS or Telephone App after clicking such a link, the browser instead redirects to a blank page whose URL is in the form sms:+123456789 or +123456789.

I've tried removing the body, including or excluding the country code, using + or 00 as the international dialing prefix.

```
<a href='tel:+1-800-555-5555' target='_blank'>call</a>
<a href='sms:+1-800-555-5555?body=test' target='_blank'>sms</a>
```

This issue was not 100% consistent over all of the devices where I have tested this. The issue is that in a browser (on a company intranet site) we need the ability to quickly make calls and send messages with prefilled data like phone number and with sms messages body text ideally as well. Such links worked fine on devices running Android 4, 5, 6, 7 but on Android 8 and 9, these links were broken. I have tested this particularly on Asus Zenfone 5 devices with Android 8 and 9. The expected behavior is: an `<a>` link is clicked, the browser starts an intent, the Phone app with a predialed number (`<a href='tel:...'>`) pops up or the SMS app with a prefilled number and body of an SMS message pops up (`<a href='sms:...?body=...'>`). Instead, either nothing happens, or a new browser tab opens with the href URI in the address bar. I have tested and had this behavior on all my Android 8 and 9 devices using Chrome, Firefox Focus, Firefox, Edge on both 8 and 9, but not in any of those browsers on Android 5 and 6 (where the links work as expected). I always used the same HTML file. Not even w3schools and other example code scripts worked on of the Asus Zenfone 5s.

Comment: I guess you came to know that android is not providing things handy anymore in latest releases so now it's the time that you should create your own subclass to  WebViewClient and handle those type of URLs self. Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient

Comment: Yes, indeed, I was very strongly considering this possibility, but in certain contexts using a custom WebView was technically impractical. Thank you for your time @Harpreet

Comment: OK, a new OS update has been pushed onto one of the devices and the following is now becoming clear: it may be partially an error/misunderstanding on my part that I specify ``target='_blank'`` on all my `a`'s and when I removed it, at least the phone number gets filled out in the Phone app and SMS app.

Comment: I have just hit this problem trying to make a support call from an App on my phone (so I don't control any aspect of how the link is presented).